# Bigger parenthesis Jupyter LaTeX

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, jupyter

I'm trying to use LaTeX formatting in a Jupyter notebook, and can't seem to get the parenthesis size I want. I'm currently using:

`$$\textrm{hav}(\theta) = \sin^{2} \Bigg( \frac{\theta}{0} \Bigg)$$`

but the size of the parentheses remains unchanged. Does anyone else have this problem / know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

A part that you should use `\Biggl` and `\Biggr` to get the correct spacing (and notice that this is probably MathJax, not exactly LaTeX), seems to work for me here:

[image]

[image]